# Change The Character Encoding

Tags: encoding, character-encoding, eclipse-cdt

I'm having some problems when i try to save my project in *Eclipse*. The error is because of the character encoding that is *Cp1252* that is because i copyed the file from another that i have created in my *Linux* computer, then i cant save my file in *Eclipse*, but how i can solve this problem? But if is needed here is an screenshot of the error:
[Encoding Error http://www.uploadimagens.com/upload/2dfccb154f30a1ccd39f2e3a9697e5cf.jpg](http://www.uploadimagens.com/upload/2dfccb154f30a1ccd39f2e3a9697e5cf.jpg)

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

from this mail thread-->
dev.eclipse.org/mhonarc/lists/cdt-dev/msg16205.html

So I can reliably make the problem come and go using Preferences > C/C++ > Environment.
There I set LANG to en_US.UTF-8 (what it was from cmd line environment) then the problem comes back when i launch from Finder.
So launching from the command line, I can UNset it there (hit "Undefine" button for that env. variable which shows its value as !! )
to fix it.